# How to convert this sql query into hql

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *,CONCAT(org_name,'|',email_id) txt
      FROM t_organization) a
WHERE txt LIKE '%o%';
```

How to write hql for this

Answer (score 0):

check below web link:
(related to sql to hql query)

```
http://forums.devshed.com/java-help-9/sql-hql-589692.html
```

Comment: How to write query inside query in hql like select* from (select * from table where 'some condi..');

Comment: session.createQuery("select count(*) as totalCount , cat.category_name, cat.category_id From BlogsEntryCategory cat " +
            "where cat.entry_id in ( select blog.entry_id from BlogsEntry blog where blog.blog_id = 1132) " +
            "group by cat.category_name")

Answer (score 0):

Go through below link nested hql in hibernate you will understand

```
http://learningviacode.blogspot.in/2012/12/hql-and-nested-queries.html
```